# "the problem was my nerves" or "the problem were my nerves"?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

> They tried anti-acids, also anxiety drugs in case the problem **was** my
>   nerves. In the end, they sent me home since my life wasn’t in danger.

Should it be *was* or *were* and why?

I tried using [Google](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=%22in%20case%20the%20problem%20was%22&rlz=1C1ASUC_enTW628TW628&ei=WTR5WrmiD8yv0ATRt7kQ&start=10&sa=N&biw=1896&bih=934) but I couldn't get an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should definitely be *was* because the subject of the clause *the problem was my nerves*, which is *the problem*, is a singular thing. And if the subject is singular, the main verb of the sentence or clause should match the subject in number. It's the subject that dictates whether the main verb takes on a singular or plural form and not the object. And it's never the other way around. It's simple as that.

For example:

> I won't be able to go out tonight. **The problem is my parents.** They're not gonna let me leave the house.

In this sentence, the subject is *the problem*, the verb is *is* and the object is *my parents*. Since the subject is singular, the verb must agree with the subject in number. That's why it's *is*. The object has no say here whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

The correct choice is: "The problem was my nerves."

The verb should agree with the subject of the sentence, which is singular: "the problem".

If you were to reverse the sentence, making "my nerves" the subject and "the problem" the predicative complement, then you would use "were": "My nerves were the problem."

(In your example, you use the term "anti-acids". I would instead say "antacids".)

Comment: I agree but "my nerves" is not an object; it's a predicative complement.

Comment: Thanks @user178049 -- I corrected the terminology as it appears in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A sentence in the form "A is B" is a copular sentence, and sometimes it is possible invert a copular sentence to give "B is A" with the same meaning.

This process is called copular inversion

In this example "The problem is my nerves" can be treated as the inversion of "My nerves are the problem"

The verb should normally agree with the subject, and so the inversion has a different verb form.